# Login to Apigee management API from Java client app

Tags: apigee

Need to Login to Apigee management API from Java client app to collect the proxy end points.

> Ref:
> https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/get-started/api-get-started?hl=en_US#gcloud

The above sample login works from gcloud but we need to call the management APIs from Java web application as a scheduled job. This token expires shortly. What is the recommended method to get token in Java app for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here at Apigee community portal:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/List-details-of-all-API-Proxies-in-the-Organization-from-ApigeeX/m-p/410578